# Spring Boot application in Google App Engine can't connect to Cloud SQL

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm not sure what else I'm missing here, but my application is failing on start with:

```
Message    : The connection attempt failed.

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:72) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1670) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar!/:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:75) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

My `app.yaml` is

```
runtime: java11
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: recruiters-wtf:europe-west2:recruiters-wtf=tcp:5432
```

while my `application.properties` contains:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.1:5432/${DB_NAME:recruiters_wtf}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASS}
```

What else am I missing? The database is being successfully used by a Kubernetes deployment of the same application.

Following kurtisvg's answer, I change the connection string to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://google/recruiters_wtf?cloudSqlInstance=recruiters-wtf:europe-west2:recruiters-wtf=tcp:5432&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=${DB_USER}&password=${DB_PASS}
```

I already had postgres-socket-factory installed. That change the error to:

```
Message    : The connection attempt failed.

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:72) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1670) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar!/:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.doConnect(UnixSocketChannel.java:127) ~[jnr-unixsocket-0.23.jar!/:na]
    at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.connect(UnixSocketChannel.java:136) ~[jnr-unixsocket-0.23.jar!/:na]
    at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.open(UnixSocketChannel.java:68) ~[jnr-unixsocket-0.23.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect(CoreSocketFactory.java:180) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.0.15.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:71) ~[postgres-socket-factory-1.0.15.jar!/:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:67) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar!/:42.2.6]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `beta_settings` entry in your `app.yaml` file? It's not defined for GAE Standard for Java11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine#configuring):

> App Engine standard enviroments do not support connecting to the Cloud
>   SQL instance using TCP. Your code should not try to access the
>   instance using an IP address (such as 127.0.0.1 or 172.17.0.1) unless
>   you have configured Serverless VPC Access.

First, you'll need to remove the `beta_settings` entry in your `app.yaml` file since:

- it is intended for App Engine Flexible (and actually instruct the platform to spin up a sidecar container running the CloudSQL proxy, which you don't need with Socket Factory for JDBC)
- the syntax you used with `=tcp:5432` would actually instructs the CloudSQL proxy to connect via TCP port.

So your Base JDBC url should look like `jdbc:postgresql://google/recruiters_wtf`

Your full datasource url would be (note the removed `=tcp:5432` part):

```
jdbc:postgresql://google/recruiters_wtf?cloudSqlInstance=recruiters-wtf:europe-west2:recruiters-wtf&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=${DB_USER}&password=${DB_PASS}
```

Finally, note that, as mentioned in the link I provided above:

> The PostgreSQL standard requires the Unix socket to have a
>   .s.PGSQL.5432 suffix in the socket path. Some libraries apply this
>   suffix automatically, but others require you to specify the socket
>   path as follows: /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "${DB_USER}"` but that's progress! I would have sworn I tested this combinations of settings, but clearly I didn't.

Comment: I'm going to explore from here, but if you have any recommendations, they are welcome.

Comment: you need to ensure the service account used has the correct role/permissions (Cloud SQL Client for example), although the connection seems successful so it seems to be a permission issue to the database itself. Have you tried hard-coding the username and pwd as a test?

Comment: Hard-coding the username and password works and the app is up and running. It is still not clear to me how the username and password should be correctly and securely handled.

Comment: As in... should they somehow be injected by App Engine based on some configuration or should I use KMS

Comment: You can set them as environment variables in  the [`app.yaml` file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements).

Comment: If you prefer to avoid hard-coding them in the `app.yaml` file to be able to commit the file in a source repository you may want to have look at these SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502945/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-the-app-yaml-using-cloud-build/53503450#53503450) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57460088/4926605)

Comment: Those two answers seem to be offloading the work to Cloud Build, which I'm not using and I'm not sure I will though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that you are using DB_NAME:recruiters_wtf, shoudn't that be DB_NAME?

Attempt to use: `spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name` if not.

Also please make sure to deploy with [beta](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/deploy)

Let me know.

Comment: `DB_NAME:recruiters_wtf` resolves to the environment variable DB_NAME and if not to recruiters_wtf.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that one of two things is occurring that allow your k8s cluster to connect:
1. You are using a Private IP
2. You are using a Public IP, and added your k8s cluster to the whitelist

If you are using a private IP to connect, you'll have to [configure Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) to allow App Engine to connect.

If you are using a Public IP, you won't be able to add App Engine to your whitelist because there is no guarantee what IP it connects from. Instead, I suggest using the [Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) to authenticate your connections instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am indeed using a public IP. I had the Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory installed, but maybe improperly configured. Correcting the configuration changed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the service account for your service has one of the following IAM roles:

`Cloud SQL Client (preferred)
 Cloud SQL Editor
 Cloud SQL Admin
 Or, you can manually assign the following IAM permissions:`

`cloudsql.instances.connect`
`cloudsql.instances.get`